# A hopefully simple inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, real-numbers

im trying to solve the following inequality:

Let $c, d, e \geq 0$ and $p > q \geq 0$, satisfying $c^p \leq e + d c^q$. Then there exists a constant $C > 0$, depending only on $p$ and $q$, such that
$$ c^p \leq C(e + d^{\frac{p}{p-q}}) $$

Right now I have no idea how to prove this, so I'm thankful for every clue.

[I](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwFY9.png) found this inequality in "[Regularization of Inverse Problems](https://zbmath.org/0859.65054)" (Engl, Hanke, Neubauer) [in the proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JH6iP.png) of Theorem 10.12. I saw this conclusion in another paper, so I was quite confident that this statement holds, but I couldn't prove it.

Comment: where is this from? How confident are you that the inequality is true, and why?

Comment: @CalvinKhor I found this inequality in "Regularization of Inverse Problems" (Engl, Hanke, Neubauer) in the proof of Theorem 10.12. I saw this conclusion in another paper, so I was quite confident that this statement holds, but I couldn't prove it.

Comment: OK. I added this information to your question body; if I find time I will think about your question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\frac{p}{p-q}$ and $\frac{p}{q}$ are Hölder conjugates we can apply Young's inequality to $dc^q$ to get
$$
c^p \leq e + dc^q \leq e + \frac{d^\frac{p}{p-q}}{\frac{p}{p-q}} + \frac{(c^q)^\frac{p}{q}}{\frac{p}{q}} = e + \frac{p-q}{p}d^\frac{p}{p-q} + \frac{q}{p}c^p.
$$
Solving this for $c^p$ we obtain
$$
c^p \leq \frac{p}{p-q}e + d^\frac{p}{p-q} \leq \frac{p}{p-q}\left(e + d^\frac{p}{p-q}\right).
$$